# handling function on PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a 2 select statements which extract data from different tables based on some criteria (one date parameter). With a third one I get the result.

**Query 1** - extract payments per claim_file - **parameter '2020-10-31'**

```
select
    p."PSN" 
    , p."PNR" 
    , d_p."Index" as claim_file_index
    , d_p."DAMFileNr" as claim_file
    , d_p."DAMDate" as claim_date
    , d_p."DAMAvizDate" as claim_notif_date
    , ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN d_pay."EID"='10' THEN d_pay."PAYVal"
                    ELSE d_pay."PAYVal"*exch_p."EXCValue" end) as NUMERIC),2) as plata_LEI
    , pr."Index" as index_pr
    , r."Index" as index_risk
into claims_paid
from "DAM" as d_p
JOIN "DAMPay" as d_pay on d_p."Index"=d_pay."DID"
JOIN "Pols" as p on p."Index" = d_p."PID"
JOIN "PolsRisc" as pr on d_pay."PRID" = pr."Index"
JOIN "Riscs" as r on r."Index" = pr."RID"
JOIN "EXCValues" exch_p ON exch_p."EID"=d_pay."EID"
where (d_pay."EID"='10' or exch_p."AtDate"='2020-10-31') and d_pay."PAYDate" <= '2020-10-31'
group by 
    p."PSN" 
    , p."PNR" 
    , d_p."Index" 
    , d_p."DAMFileNr" 
    , d_p."DAMDate"
    , d_p."DAMAvizDate" 
    , pr."Index"
    , r."Index";
```

**Ouery 2** - Extract constituted reserves per claim_file **parameter '2020-10-31'**

```
select
    p."PSN" 
    , p."PNR" 
    , d_r."Index" as claim_file_index
    , d_r."DAMFileNr" as claim_file
    , d_r."DAMDate" as claim_date
    , d_r."DAMAvizDate" as claim_notif_date
    , ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN d_rez."EID"='10' THEN d_rez."RDAM"
                    ELSE d_rez."RDAM"*exch_r."EXCValue" end) as NUMERIC),2) as rez_const_LEI
    , pr."Index" as index_pr
    , r."Index" as index_risk
into claims_rez_const
from "DAM" as d_r
JOIN "DAMRez" as d_rez on d_r."Index"=d_rez."DID"
JOIN "Pols" as p on p."Index" = d_r."PID"
JOIN "PolsRisc" as pr on d_rez."PRID" = pr."Index"
JOIN "Riscs" as r on r."Index" = pr."RID"
JOIN "EXCValues" exch_r ON exch_r."EID"=d_rez."EID"
where (d_rez."EID"='10' or exch_r."AtDate"='2020-10-31') and d_rez."RDAMDate" <= '2020-10-31'
and (d_r."IsClass" = 'false' or (d_r."IsClass" = 'true' and d_r."ClassDate" >='2020-11-01'))
and (d_r."IsClosed" = 'false' or (d_r."IsClosed" = 'true' and d_r."ClosedDate" >='2020-11-01')) 
group by 
    p."PSN" 
    , p."PNR"
    , d_r."Index" 
    , d_r."DAMFileNr" 
    , d_r."DAMDate"
    , d_r."DAMAvizDate" 
    , pr."Index"
    , r."Index";
```

**Query 3** - getting the result (const - paid)

```
select 
    r_c."PSN" 
    , r_c."PNR" 
    , r_c."claim_file_index"
    , r_c."claim_file"
    , r_c."claim_date"
    , r_c."claim_notif_date"
    , r_c."rez_const_lei" as rez_const_Lei
    , coalesce(r_p."plata_lei",0) as plata_Lei
    , coalesce(r_c."rez_const_lei" - coalesce(r_p."plata_lei",0),0) as rez_ram_Lei
from claims_rez_const r_c
left join claims_paid r_p on r_c."claim_file_index"=r_p."claim_file_index"
where coalesce(r_c."rez_const_lei" - coalesce(r_p."plata_lei",0),0) != 0 ;
```

I want to create a function what goes through this 3 steps and return the result based on the introduced parameter (calc_date date).
I was trying to create a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION claims_rez_ram(calc_date date)
RETURNS TABLE (
                Serie varchar(50)
                , Numar varchar(50)
                , Claim_File_Index integer
                , Claim_File varchar(30)
                , Claim_Date date
                , Claim_Notif_Date date
                , Rez_Const_Lei double precision
                , Plata_Lei double precision
                , Rez_Ram double precision) as $func$ 
declare
begin
    
with claims_paid as (
select
    p."PSN" 
    , p."PNR" 
    , d_p."Index" as claim_file_index
    , d_p."DAMFileNr" as claim_file
    , d_p."DAMDate" as claim_date
    , d_p."DAMAvizDate" as claim_notif_date
    , ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN d_pay."EID"='10' THEN d_pay."PAYVal"
                    ELSE d_pay."PAYVal"*exch_p."EXCValue" end) as NUMERIC),2) as plata_LEI
    , pr."Index" as index_pr
    , r."Index" as index_risk
from "DAM" as d_p
JOIN "DAMPay" as d_pay on d_p."Index"=d_pay."DID"
JOIN "Pols" as p on p."Index" = d_p."PID"
JOIN "PolsRisc" as pr on d_pay."PRID" = pr."Index"
JOIN "Riscs" as r on r."Index" = pr."RID"
JOIN "EXCValues" exch_p ON exch_p."EID"=d_pay."EID"
where (d_pay."EID"='10' or exch_p."AtDate"=calc_date) and d_pay."PAYDate" <= calc_date
group by 
    p."PSN" 
    , p."PNR" 
    , d_p."Index" 
    , d_p."DAMFileNr" 
    , d_p."DAMDate"
    , d_p."DAMAvizDate" 
    , pr."Index"
    , r."Index"
 ),
 claims_rez_const as (
 select
    p."PSN" 
    , p."PNR" 
    , d_r."Index" as claim_file_index
    , d_r."DAMFileNr" as claim_file
    , d_r."DAMDate" as claim_date
    , d_r."DAMAvizDate" as claim_notif_date
    , ROUND(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN d_rez."EID"='10' THEN d_rez."RDAM"
                    ELSE d_rez."RDAM"*exch_r."EXCValue" end) as NUMERIC),2) as rez_const_LEI
    , pr."Index" as index_pr
    , r."Index" as index_risk

from "DAM" as d_r
JOIN "DAMRez" as d_rez on d_r."Index"=d_rez."DID"
JOIN "Pols" as p on p."Index" = d_r."PID"
JOIN "PolsRisc" as pr on d_rez."PRID" = pr."Index"
JOIN "Riscs" as r on r."Index" = pr."RID"
JOIN "EXCValues" exch_r ON exch_r."EID"=d_rez."EID"
where (d_rez."EID"='10' or exch_r."AtDate"=calc_date) and d_rez."RDAMDate" <= calc_date
and (d_r."IsClass" = 'false' or (d_r."IsClass" = 'true' and d_r."ClassDate" >=(calc_date + interval '1 day')))
and (d_r."IsClosed" = 'false' or (d_r."IsClosed" = 'true' and d_r."ClosedDate" >=(calc_date + interval '1 day'))) 
group by 
    p."PSN" 
    , p."PNR"
    , d_r."Index" 
    , d_r."DAMFileNr" 
    , d_r."DAMDate"
    , d_r."DAMAvizDate" 
    , pr."Index"
    , r."Index"
)

 select 
    r_c."PSN" 
    , r_c."PNR" 
    , r_c."claim_file_index"
    , r_c."claim_file"
    , r_c."claim_date"
    , r_c."claim_notif_date"
    , r_c."rez_const_lei" as rez_const_Lei
    , coalesce(r_p."plata_lei",0) as plata_Lei
    , coalesce(r_c."rez_const_lei" - coalesce(r_p."plata_lei",0),0) as rez_ram_Lei
from claims_rez_const r_c
left join claims_paid r_p on r_c."claim_file_index"=r_p."claim_file_index"
where coalesce(r_c."rez_const_lei" - coalesce(r_p."plata_lei",0),0) != 0 ;

end;

$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

When I run this function using:

```
select * from claims_rez_ram('2020-10-31')
```

I have an error:

SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: query has no destination for result data
Hint: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
Where: PL/pgSQL function claims_rez_ram(date) line 5 at SQL statement

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgresql function whenever the return type is `table`, then there must be a `return query` statement in the function body before `select` query. So add `return query` after `begin` in your function body, your error will be resolved

Comment: Thanks for your help Akhilesh. Unfortunately, I was trying this method too. When I add 'return query' i get another error: SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: structure of query does not match function result type
  Detail: Returned type numeric does not match expected type double precision in column 7.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function claims_rez_ram(date) line 4 at RETURN QUERY

Comment: You are getting this error because in function declaration column 7  is `double precision` type but 7th columns `rez_const_lei` in your select query is `numeric` type. Please note that data type of columns returned by select query and columns in function declaration should be symmetric. if it is not same then you have to cast it explicitly.